# What does "dynamic creation of variables" mean?

Tags: python, dynamic

I am reading [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop) and I don't understand the word "dynamically".

Does it refer to the fact that the variable should be created after the `pyc` has been created?

In the following code:

```
x = 3 
globals()['y'] = 4
```

Is `y` created dynamically?

Comment: You can choose the name of the variable (`y`) at runtime. `globals()[var_name] ...`

Comment: Note that this is **almost always** a very very bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in your example `y` is created dynamically. Strictly speaking, it has nothing to do with it being created before or after the .pyc file. It has to do with it being created as a side effect of some other code being run.

You can dynamically create variables in other ways, too. For example, with exec:

```
exec("x=42")
print(x)
```

While such things are possible, they should generally be avoided because it makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: In this case, at least the name of the variable is hard-coded, and in theory the interpreter could optimize the call to `exec` to `x=42`. The dynamic aspect comes in when you realize that the string passed to `exec` could be the result of user input: `name = input("Pick a variable name"); exec("{0}=42".format(name))`. Now, your program has a variable whose name is *completely* unknown until the program runs. This raises the question, "How would your code subsequently use such a variable?". (Answer: with difficulty.)